# How do I trap a redirect from javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have this odd bug that causes a 302 redirect to another page on my site and I can't seem to track the source. The bug is very random and hard to track.

I have 2 or more dropdowns on a page for users to select from. Selecting from the first loads the second, second loads third etc. This is done thru posting back on the onchange event, all .net.

Additionally through jquery onblur is wired up to the change event. I'm not sure why but I'm guessing that whomever wanted to unselect the dropdown after a selection was made, most likely to prevent a scrolling mouse wheel from changing the selection and causing several post backs.

When I unhook the onblur the bug goes away but I need to know whats going on. Some how onblur is causing a sequence of events that results in a 302 redirect without even getting to the server. This would suggest a javascript location change. How can I stop at the location change and see what js is triggering this?

Any suggestions ?

Thank you.

Comment: How does one cause, or detect, an HTTP 302 without an HTTP transaction? Also, I think we're gonna need to see some code...

Answer (score 0):

A redirect is an instruction to the browser, not the page, so JavaScript can't see it.

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure it's a 302 causing the location change? I would start by loading your favorite dev tools (I like chrome) and see if you are actually getting a 302.

If you are getting a 302, you're going to have to post some server side code. If not, I would place some js debug points and go from there.

Comment: absolutely sure. I just can't track the source of the redirect.

Comment: The problem was a bug in jquery when you bind to a blur event it triggers 2 posts. I can't seem to find the link right now though. Its still an open bug in jquery.